# React Material UI Theme provider doesn't change colors version 5x

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm building an app in NextJs that must support custom themes. By reading the Material UI documentation to change the primary color something like should work:

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@emotion/react';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

const theme = createTheme({
    pallete: {
      primary: #fefefe,
    }
});


export default (_) => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Button>Primary</Button>
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

However the color of the button never changes, I'm I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ThemeProvider` from `@mui` package, not from `@emotion`.

Answer (score 0):

use - import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from **'@mui/material'**